# Different text detection result from Google Vision API

Tags: .net, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

Get different result for text detection from .Net code and demo app for the same image [google vision api result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H21rL.png) and [.net result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heYZt.png)

this is my code:

```
            var response = vision.Images.Annotate(
            new BatchAnnotateImagesRequest()
            {
                Requests = new[]
                {
                    new AnnotateImageRequest()
                    {
                        Features = new[]
                        {
                            new Feature()
                            {
                                Type =
                                    "TEXT_DETECTION"
                            }
                        },
                        Image = image
                    }
                }
            }).Execute();
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with PHP library, result is different between browser and REST API call, why?

Answer (score 6):

As noted in Emil's answer, you want the `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` feature rather than `TEXT_DETECTION`. However, you can do it all rather more simply than with the current code.

Rather than using [Google.Apis.Vision.V1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Vision.v1/) (which it looks like you're doing, and which uses the REST endpoint), I'd suggest using [Google.Cloud.Vision.V1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1/) (which uses the gRPC endpoint, and is hopefully easier to use. Disclaimer: I work on the latter library). You *can* do most work with the REST endpoint, mind you.

Here's a complete example using the latter library.

```
using Google.Cloud.Vision.V1;
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
        var image = Image.FromUri("https://i.stack.imgur.com/H21rL.png");
        var annotations = client.DetectDocumentText(image);
        var paragraphs = annotations.Pages
            .SelectMany(page => page.Blocks)
            .SelectMany(block => block.Paragraphs);
        foreach (var para in paragraphs)
        {
            var box = para.BoundingBox;
            Console.WriteLine($"Bounding box: {string.Join(" / ", box.Vertices.Select(v => $"({v.X}, {v.Y})"))}");
            var symbols = string.Join("", para.Words.SelectMany(w => w.Symbols).SelectMany(s => s.Text));
            Console.WriteLine($"Paragraph: {symbols}");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

That loses the spaces between the symbols, but shows that all the text is being detected - and the method call to perform the actual detection is very simple:

```
var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
var image = Image.FromUri("https://i.stack.imgur.com/H21rL.png");
var annotations = client.DetectDocumentText(image);
```

Most of the code above is handling the response.

Comment: Thanks, the detection is not method related, the result should be the same for both gRPC and REST API, it just that it has a dense OCR mode which detects more text compared to OCR.

Comment: @EmilBorconi: Sure - I was just trying to show that it's rather easier to do via the gRPC library. Will clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#ImageContext) when using Vision API we should use `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION`

```
+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TEXT_DETECTION          | Run OCR.                                                                                                        |
+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION | Run dense text document OCR. Takes precedence when both DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION and TEXT_DETECTION are present. |
+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Therefore the code should look like this:

```
var response = vision.Images.Annotate(
            new BatchAnnotateImagesRequest()
            {
                Requests = new[]
                {
                    new AnnotateImageRequest()
                    {
                        Features = new[]
                        {
                            new Feature()
                            {
                                Type =
                                    "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"
                            }
                        },
                        Image = image
                    }
                }
            }).Execute();
```